# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 before Windows8.1 Error 0xc000000e the BCD of your PC is missing or contains error

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bcd, ubuntu-14.04

I install Windows usually before Ubuntu, but because there wasn't Windows after experiencing some hard drive problem I installed Ubuntu-Gnome-14.04 before Windows, but I am unable to install either Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 afterwards.

The error I encountered every time I try to make the installation using the USB key (because the DVD drive of my laptop is broken) is:

### Windows Boot Manager

> Windows failed to start. 
>     A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.

```
  File: \Boot\BCD
  Status: Oxc000000e
  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains error.
```

How do I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have MBR or GPT on your drive?

Comment: No I don't think. I've completely formatted my drive.

Comment: If your computer is using UEFI, Ubuntu might have formatted drive as GPT, and when you try to install Windows, it confuses it

Comment: So, How to install Ubuntu-14.04 using UEFI in order that Windows recognizes the partition  ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2004518) is Microsoft's response to a similar problem.

Attempt 1: Try Windows Repair.

Attempt 2: Use Bootrec.exe to rebuild BCD.

Attempt 3: Us BCDedit.exe to restore BCD manually.

Comment: The problem is that Windows does not boot so I can not access the repair process. Every time I put the USB key, I obtain the error I've mention above.

Comment: @user3452538 It sounds like you need to take the HDD to another computer so that you can run either Bootrec.exe or BCDedit.exe.